# How to Join Two tables in HIVE.

Tags: join, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two tables A and B that both have the following structure.

```
// Table A

Name    Age    actualdate    no

// Table B

City    sdate  edate         id
```

I wish to obtain all the fields from A and B using JOIN where, id = no and sdate <= actualdate and edate >= actualdate.

I tried as below using where clause, but it's not working.

```
select v3.*, t3.* from A v3
JOIN
B t3
where v3.id = t3.no and
      v3.sdate <= t3.actualdate and
      v3.edate >= t3.actualdate
limit 1;
```

Using On clause :

```
select v3.*, t3.* from A v3
    JOIN
    B t3
    ON ( v3.id = t3.no and
          v3.sdate <= t3.actualdate and
          v3.edate >= t3.actualdate )
    limit 1;
```

Unfortunately, Hive doesn't support equijoin. Is there a way to achieve the above using joins?

Comment: what is the error you are getting when you are trying to do the join?

Comment: When I use "ON" clause , I am getting error as:FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'actualdate'. and when i am using "WHERE" clause, it's not throwing error but I am not getiing any result. But I if I remove the portion "and v3.sdate <= t3.actualdate and v3.edate >= t3.actualdate" from "ON" clause it's working fine but with no condtion check.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the <= and >= conditions inside the ON clause, you can use WHERE to do the filtering.

```
select v3.*, t3.* from A t3
JOIN
B v3
ON ( v3.id = t3.no)
WHERE v3.sdate <= t3.actualdate and
      v3.edate >= t3.actualdate
limit 1;
```

Note: your t3 and v3 aliases were interchanged.