# HIVE for each row from one table join all rows from another table

Tags: join, hive

In table `A` I have dates from `2014-01-01` to `2014-12-31`

```
 action_date
 2014-01-01
 2014-01-02
 2014-01-03
 ...
 2014-12-31
```

In table `B` I have some information like

```
id name action_date deletion_date
1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03
2  tom  2014-06-02  2014-06-30
3  lola 2013-12-30  2014-01-01
4  pete 2014-12-29  1970-01-01
```

I want to join row from B table to each `A` table row if `activation_date<=action_date AND (action_date<=deletion_date OR deletion_date='1970-01-01')`

e.g.

```
 action_date id name action_date deletion_date
 2014-01-01  1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03
 2014-01-01  3  lola 2013-12-30  2014-01-01
 2014-01-02  1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03
 2014-01-03  1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03
   [...]
 2014-02-03  1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03

 2014-06-02  2  tom  2014-06-02  2014-06-30
 2014-06-03  2  tom  2014-06-02  2014-06-30
   [...]
 2014-06-03  2  tom  2014-06-02  2014-06-30
 2014-12-29  4  pete 2014-12-29  1970-01-01 
 2014-12-30  4  pete 2014-12-29  1970-01-01 
 2014-12-31  4  pete 2014-12-29  1970-01-01
```

I tried to use next query in Hive and in PostgreSQL.

```
   SELECT a.action_date, b.*
   FROM  b
   JOIN  a ON action_date>= activation_date
           AND (action_date<=deletion_date OR deletion_date='1970-01-01')
```

In PostgreSQL it works fine, but in Hive returns 
`semanticexception [error 10017]: line 16:3 both left and right aliases encountered in join 'action_date'`

How to solve this problem in Hive?

Comment: Instead of using the <= and >= conditions inside the ON clause, you can use WHERE to do the [filtering][1].

    select a.*, t3.* from A t3
    JOIN
    B v3
    ON ( v3.id = t3.no)
    WHERE v3.sdate <= t3.actualdate AND
          v3.edate >= t3.actualdate


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832513/how-to-join-two-tables-in-hive

Comment: @Mus7afa, Then what condition should be used in ON statement?

Comment: check your query, "ON action_date >= activation_date" you make mistake this line. it's should be "ON action_date = activation_date".

SELECT a.action_date, b.* FROM b 
JOIN a ON (a. action_date = b. action_date)
WHERE b.action_date <= b.deletion_date OR b.deletion_date='1970-01-01'.

and you can use "ON (TRUE)" but it can be  slow.

Answer (score 0):

As per error, issue is occurring due to same column name in both tables. Use alias for tables and in condition, give alias.. This will solve the issue.