# how to merge two tables in hive

Tags: hive

As I'm new to Hive I always ended up with a lot of problems,
I want to join two tables and create a single partitioned table based on the country column.

```
select * from mergetable limit 5;
```

OK

> 148.113.13.214    United States
>
> 4.175.198.160 United States
>
> 24.146.153.181    United States
>
> 203.156.137.68    Thailand
>
> 114.127.210.217   Indonesia

```
show create table mergetable;
```

OK

```
`CREATE TABLE `mergetable`(
  `ipaddrss` string, 
  `country` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT;`  




CREATE TABLE `mergetable1`(
  `website` string, 
  `dt` string, 
  `tm` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Join Two tables in HIVE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832513/how-to-join-two-tables-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  select_statement
  UNION ALL
  select_statement
) unionResult
```

See the detailed syntax and other use cases of concatenation of two tables here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Union